# Specify many-to-many relationship in buffalo model

Tags: go, buffalo

Please does anyone know how to specify a many-to-many relationship in buffalo models?

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: On the documentation for buffalo, only one to one, and one-to-many relationship was specified. That is reason for the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gobuffalo many_to_many ...

```
type Organization struct {
    ID               int                `json:"id" db:"id"`
    Users            Users              `many_to_many:"user_organizations"`
}


type User struct {
    ID                int                `json:"id" db:"id"`
    Organizations     Organizations      `many_to_many:"user_organizations" json:"-"`
}


type UserOrganization struct {
    ID             int          `json:"id" db:"id"`
    OrganizationID int          `json:"organization_id" db:"organization_id"`
    UserID         int          `json:"user_id" db:"user_id"`
    User           User         `belongs_to:"users"`
    Organization   Organization `belongs_to:"organizations"`
}
```

Each of these structs are in their own models/*.go file

https://gobuffalo.io/en/docs/db/relations